# MySql match against not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM contact_socials 
    force index(url) 
    WHERE MATCH(url) against ( list of urls  in boolean mode );
```

This works well with a small number of urls, but when the list goes to 5-10k urls and more the query becomes very slow, 30 minutes or so in some cases. The table itself has about 40k records.

When I ask for `explain` on the query I can see that it is `Using where` although a `show index` reveals that the table has a `fulltext` index on the key `url`.

Why doesn't the query use the index? How do I make it start using it?

Comment: Do you mean you have a FTS expression with 10,000 terms? I think you're in uncharted territory here. No one I know uses FTS functions like that.

Comment: "using where" is supposed to be there; you have to check the "type" or the "key" in the `explain` output to see if it is using the fulltext index. Otherwise: especially for searching urls, a fulltext search seems to be inapt. `xxx.com/word1/word2/word3/word4` is usually completely different than `xxy.com/word1/word2/word3/word4`, so there might be a better way to model or analyze your data (e.g. indexing the domain name). You can probably read all 40k rows, compare every word with every word of your search list, let the application sleep for 29 minutes and still be faster than 30 minutes.

Comment: Can't you use LIKE instead of MATCH? domain in urls should be unique, and maybe you can use that to your advantage,